# Translucent JLabel not properly showing background

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have the following line:

```
        label.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 150, 0, 50));
```

I place this in a mouseReleased method within a MouseAdapter.

Basically, I want to make the label highlight itself in translucent green when I click on it.

I have several labels in a panel, all with this MouseAdapter added to them.

My problem is this:

-When I click on the label, it shows the translucent green color, but it is showing the background of ANOTHER JLabel, not the one I click on.

No matter which label I click on, it always paints the background of the same label.

-Whenever I click on a label, it repeats the same background. 
-Weirdly, every time I click on a JLabel, the opacity of the green color seems to increase, as if it were painting the translucent green over itself each time I click on a new JLabel.

Any tips on what's going on? Should I try to post an SSCCE on this? Or is there a simple answer I'm missing. The reason that I didn't post an SSCCE yet is that my code is large and spread across multiple files, so I must trim it out first.

Comment: The code would help us greatly. In fact, you may find the problem yourself while recreating a self-contained sample.

Comment: You could at least post the code where the `label` variable is last assigned to. That is the code that is most likely to be relevant as to why it is picking the wrong label!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the probable problem and a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Swing only has a concept of opaque or transparent components, it does not, by itself, know how to deal with a component that is opaque, but has a translucent background color.  As far as Swing is concerned, the component is opaque, so it doesn't paint what's underneath the component.

Normally, I would supply a `alpha` value which I would then apply to a solid background, but in this example, I'm simply filling the background with what ever background color you supply, so unless you supply a translucent color, it will be filled with a solid color.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTranslucentLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTranslucentLabel();
    }

    public TestTranslucentLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    TranslucentLabel label = new TranslucentLabel("This is a translucent label");
                    label.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128));
                    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

                    JLabel background = new JLabel();
                    background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/swhitehead/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/Rampage_Small.png"))));
                    background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    background.add(label);

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(background);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TranslucentLabel extends JLabel {

        public TranslucentLabel(String text, Icon icon, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(text, icon, horizontalAlignment);
        }

        public TranslucentLabel(String text, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(text, horizontalAlignment);
        }

        public TranslucentLabel(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

        public TranslucentLabel(Icon image, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(image, horizontalAlignment);
        }

        public TranslucentLabel(Icon image) {
            super(image);
        }

        public TranslucentLabel() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOpaque() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/), but why `create()/dispose()`? just good defensive practice?

Comment: @trashgod In this case, there's no real reason, I just do it by habit (and have templates set up in Netbeans to generate it ;))

Comment: @camickr Yea for fancy pictures ;)

Comment: @camickr Ohh slap :P - Personally, links disappear (not saying yours do, but I've had this problem with several answers to problems I've had and it's very annoying ;))

Comment: @camickr To be honest I solved my problem oirignally by using your link, before looking at MadProgrammer's solution. So your answer was right. You are both right!! Wish there were two checkmarks?

Comment: In fact, I was able to understand the problem more by using your link. but hey, I guess the pretty picture did get to me :S

Comment: @ThePrince `I solved my problem oirignally by using your link... I was able to understand the problem more by using your link.` I answer the question first by 12 minutes (I delete my answers if someone beats my by less than a minute so I don't clutter the forum with duplicates). I give a solution with more detail that provided more understanding of the problem. Yet you accepted this answer and people wonder why I'm frustrated? `I guess the pretty picture did get to me` - I don't provide pictures, so there is no need for me to answer future questions since you prefer sizzle over substance.

Comment: @camickr its nothing against you, but I have a personal dislike for link only answers as links tend to disappear over time, so those answers become worthless. I have nothing against the content of your blogs and I've some of those to answer some of my own questions. Had you taken the time to summarise the content of the link I would have felt less inclined to provide a fuller answer in place on the forum.

Comment: Its possible links will disappear. I think the bigger problem is all the old code out on the web. We continually answer questions based on old code that has not been updated to reflect API changes or better approaches to solve a problem. Maybe in the future the API will be fixed with a property to have transparent backgrounds work properly. Then all I have to do is go to the blog and update the blog with the new solution and voila every answer I've given on any forum in the past will automatically be up to date.

Comment: @camickr That may be true, assuming you're still about to update the blog and that is still your focus. As outlined [Provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), it recommended to provide a summary of link. The one time I did what you do on regular bases, I got slapped for it, so you will excuse me if I continue to add context to answers where I find the available answers lacking and in fact, if you were to provid summarised overview of your links, I'd probably be more willing to provide the up vote they deserve - IMHO

Comment: @camickr Again, this nothing personal, I have a think for all "link only answers", you have up most respect as a developer