# Color (Alpha) changes by mouseover till tooltip appears

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, alpha, jcheckbox

I currently try to add some instances JCheckBox with ToolTips. These ToolTips change whenever the user selects or unselect the JCheckBox (via ItemListener). But: Everytime I go over the JCheckbox it changes the Color (the Alpha) so it becomes less transparent, so it seems like the Alpha of the Background changes. It changes back as soon as I wait for the ToolTip, but this still annoys me a bit.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyBox extends JCheckBox {

private final String onSelected;
private final String onNotSelected;
private int index;



public MyBox(int index){
    super();
    this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    this.index = index;
    this.onSelected = "ABC";
    this.onNotSelected = "DEF";
    this.setToolTipText(this.onNotSelected);
    super.setOpaque(true);
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 255, 80));

    Dimension size = new Dimension(10,10);
    this.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

public int getIndex(){
    return this.index;
}

public void setTooltipFor(boolean selected){
     String setto = selected ? onSelected : onNotSelected;
     this.setToolTipText(setto);
}

public void disableEditing(){
    this.setEnabled(false);
}
}
```

And

```
public class MyListener implements ItemListener{



public MyListener(){
}



@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
    MyBox box =((MyBox) ie.getItemSelectable());

    int index = box.getIndex();

    if(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
       box.setTooltipFor(true);
    }
   else{
       box.setTooltipFor(false);
   }
} 
}
```

Of the Listener is added in another class (adding and changing works). The problem remains: Why is the alpha changing (the color becomes more opaque and darker) and how can I avoid that?

Comment: "`super.setOpaque(true);`" - you are using a translucent background, that means the component is **not** opaque. You should set the opaqueness to false instead.

Comment: Never use alpha based colors for Swing `background` properties (`JFrame` excepted), Swing components are either opaque or transparent, not translucent. If you want translucency, you need to fake it, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361432/translucent-jlabel-not-properly-showing-background/20362223#20362223)

Comment: @kiheru Sorry, but this is totally wrong: I try to set a semi-transparent color (like "new Color(0, 0, 255, 80)), so that color should be drawn. Therefore I have to set opque = true -- // -- MadProgrammer thanks for this hint. I didn't know about this.

Comment: @blackwodka86 `Therefore I have to set opque = true` - that does not solve the problem. You still need to do custom painting as demonstrated below.

Answer (score 3):

> But: Everytime I go over the JCheckbox it changes the Color (the Alpha) so it becomes less transparent

Yes, Swing does not know how to handle transparent colors properly because you are breaking the painting rules.

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and solutions. You can either:

1. Do the custom painting of the background yourself
2. Use the provided `AlphaContainer` class to do the painting for you